# Singer.io target-redshift

Tags: python, singer-io

I have a shopify store and I am trying to read the data from it using singer.io and dump it into the redshift cluster. I was able to run it successfully using postgresql but redshift is throwing an error that I am unable to understand and fix. Any help or suggestions as to how to get around this?

Below is my redshfit_config.json

```
{
   "redshift_host":"redshift-cluster-1.cepdr3dnmmcm.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com",
   "redshift_port":5439,
   "redshift_database":"dev",
   "redshift_username":"awsuser",
   "redshift_password":"Password",
   "redshift_schema":"singer",
   "default_column_length":1000,
   "target_s3":{
      "aws_access_key_id":"*Aws key id*",
      "aws_secret_access_key":"*aws access key*",
      "bucket":"singer-redshift",
      "key_prefix":"__tmp"
   }
```

and when trying to run i am getting this error

```
root@e0e876755adf:/# ~/.virtualenvs/tap-shopify/bin/tap-shopify -c config.json  --catalog catalog.json | target-redshift --config redshift_config.json
INFO GET https://testnoman.myshopify.com/admin/api/2024-01/shop.json
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/target-redshift", line 5, in <module>
    from target_redshift import cli
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/target_redshift/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from target_redshift.s3 import S3
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/target_redshift/s3.py", line 3, in <module>
    import boto3
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/boto3/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from boto3.session import Session
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/boto3/session.py", line 17, in <module>
    import botocore.session
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/botocore/session.py", line 29, in <module>
    import botocore.configloader
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/botocore/configloader.py", line 19, in <module>
    from botocore.compat import six
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/botocore/compat.py", line 25, in <module>
    from botocore.exceptions import MD5UnavailableError
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/botocore/exceptions.py", line 15, in <module>
    from botocore.vendored import requests
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/utils.py", line 26, in <module>
    from .compat import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/compat.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .packages import chardet
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import urllib3
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 38, in <module>
    from .response import HTTPResponse
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py", line 9, in <module>
    from ._collections import HTTPHeaderDict
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/_collections.py", line 1, in <module>
    from collections import Mapping, MutableMapping
ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (/usr/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)
INFO --> 200 OK 1517b
CRITICAL BrokenPipeError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/tap-shopify/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tap_shopify/__init__.py", line 213, in main
    sync()
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/tap-shopify/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tap_shopify/__init__.py", line 149, in sync
    singer.write_schema(stream["tap_stream_id"],
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/tap-shopify/lib/python3.10/site-packages/singer/messages.py", line 264, in write_schema
    write_message(
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/tap-shopify/lib/python3.10/site-packages/singer/messages.py", line 227, in write_message
    sys.stdout.flush()
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/tap-shopify/bin/tap-shopify", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('tap-shopify==1.10.0', 'console_scripts', 'tap-shopify')())
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/tap-shopify/lib/python3.10/site-packages/singer/utils.py", line 235, in wrapped
    return fnc(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/tap-shopify/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tap_shopify/__init__.py", line 228, in main
    raise ShopifyError(exc) from exc
tap_shopify.exceptions.ShopifyError: BrokenPipeError
```

If I switch the target from redshift to postgres it works fine.

I am running python 3.10